# "ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope" in standalone script

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I run the following script with `npx ts-node -i --esm --skipProject -T .\seed.ts`

```
import { readdir, readFile } from "node:fs/promises"

async function readFeedsFromFiles() {
    const data = await readdir("./seedData/feeds", {
        withFileTypes: true,
    })
        .then((files) => files.forEach((f) => f.isFile() && readFile(`./seedData/feeds/${f.name}`, "utf8")))
        .then((data) => console.log(data))

    return data
}

readFeedsFromFiles()
```

but this error is thrown

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
    at file:///C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/source/myapp/prisma/seed.ts:2:23
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:541:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:438:15)
```

How do I fix this?

```
> node -v
v18.7.0
> npx ts-node -v
v10.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `-O '{\"module\":\"es2022\"}'` to the command line options.

`npx ts-node -i --esm --skipProject -T -O '{\"module\":\"es2022\"}' .\seed.ts`